# 'fop is missing' while installing Erlang using asdf in Mac

Tags: macos, erlang

I'm getting the below error while trying to install Erlang using ASDF.

```
fop is missing
using fakefop to generate placeholder pdf file.
```

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

`fop` is used to generate documentation in PDF format. You probably won't need it, as most of the time it's easier to look up things in the documentation online, either on the official site, http://erlang.org/doc/, or using the alternative interface at https://erldocs.com/.

So you can safely ignore this error message.

Answer (score 1):

I have this error when trying to install Erlang `24.0.5`. So, I installed the `fop` dependency:

```sh
brew install libxslt fop
```

But as mentioned this was not the root cause of my installation issue.

So, I run:

```sh
export KERL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="--without-wx --without-javac"
asdf install erlang <version>
```

and I was able to finish the erlang install.

References:

- https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang#osx
- https://erlangforums.com/t/erlang-installation-using-kerl-on-mac-m1-openssl-dependency/1306/5

Answer (score 0):

Install fop:

https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

I've never bothered, though.